# Change disabled color

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I would like to change SimpleButton component default gray color of SVG Image in disabled state.

I'm using latest 2018.1 components

How to change this gray color?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like somehow define disabled icon color. If I define colored svg image icon to simple button this icon gets gray on disabled status.

Comment: While I'm still unsure exactly what you mean, generally in order to modify such things, you need to use the [DevExpress Theme Editor](https://docs.devexpress.com/WpfThemeEditor/10429/index).

Comment: I have tried with theme editor and i don't know where to set this properties